# Pass more than one argument to CreateThread

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, com, marshalling

**Question:**

- How to **pass** specifically **two** arguments to [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(VS.85).aspx), **when**:

  - Argument one, of type `SOCKET`
  - Argument two, an **interface pointer**:

  `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(Range, __uuidof(Range));`

  `RangePtr pRange; //pass pRange`

**Suggestions:**

- For interface pointer, using [CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693316.aspx), accordingly,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

create a structure of these two types and pass a pointer to it. This is the standard
way of passing data to threads over single pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating struct_thread_xyz_params, I would first use boost::thread if possible. If that wasn't an option, I would create a wrapper template function object that calls CreateThread with itself when it is constructed:

```
template <class Func>
class Thread
{
    Func m_Func;
    static DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(void* param)
    {
        Thread& pFunc = *(Thread*)param;
        pFunc();
        return S_OK;
    }
public:
    Thread(Func& func): m_Func(func){
        CreateThread(NULL,NULL,Thread::ThreadFunc,this,NULL,NULL);
    };
    void operator()()
    {
        m_Func();
    }
};
```

then if I had a function that took two args:

```
void printTwoStrings(string a, string b)
{
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
};
```

I could wrap them in a functor:

```
class StringFunc
{
    string m_a;
    string m_b;
public:
    StringFunc(string a, string b):m_a(a),m_b(b)
    {

    };
    void operator()(){
        printTwoStrings(m_a,m_b);
    }
};
```

and initiliaze an instance of that functor on demand:

```
int main()
{

    Thread<StringFunc> myThread(StringFunc("hello","world"));
    Sleep(500);
    return 0;
}
```

note that I'm sleeping at the end, you didn't say anything at all about waiting for the thread to complete... The difficulty with struct_xyz_params is that you will often need later struct_wxyz_params and the temptation to duplicate code is always high...

boost::thread is good too (but I already said that).

-Rick

Answer (score 1):

`std::pair` is your friend.

Comment: how exectly whould you convert std::pair to void* ;)

Comment: Artyom:
std::pair<SOCKET, RangePtr> pr(sock, pRange);
void* ptr = (void*)&pr;

Comment: @Peter: if the caller function goes out of scope before the thread had finished you may end with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

you could also post a WM_COPYDATA, filling a COPYDATASTRUCT at a later point after the thread is started (ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: If you have some data to be sent to your thread at a later point after creation 
1) create the COPYDATASTRUCT
2) Post the WM_COPYDATA message to the thread queue using PostThreadMessage API.

Let me know for any ...