# How to call function with parameters in the injected dll in windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dllexport, dll-injection

I want to inject my simple dll into a third-party application.
After that I want to call a function in the dll from my own process, not the process in the third-party application.

the first part in the following shows that the whole dll I test:

```
// dllmain.cpp
#include "pch.h"



extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

the second part shows the caller function in my process:

```
    // hProcess is the process in the third-party application

    // Call our exported function
    lpReturn = NULL;

    ***// I don't know how to pass parameter a and b into the exported function add in my simple dll***
    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpFunctionAddress, lpRemoteParams, NULL, NULL);

    DWORD dwOut = 0;
    while (GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &dwOut)) {
        if (dwOut != STILL_ACTIVE) {
            *ppReturn = (PVOID)dwOut;
            break;
        }
    }
```

**I don't know how to pass parameter a and b into the exported function add in my simple dll(please refers to the second part above)**

Anyone can give me a hint, or a complete example shows how to call function with parameters in the injected dll in windows ? Thx:-)

Comment: Your injecting process can't *directly* call functions on a DLL that it has injected into another process. It will have to inject more code to make those function calls in the context of the other process. Otherwise, the DLL should setup some kind of IPC server that the injector can send commands to as needed. Also, you can't use `CreateRemoteThread()` to call functions whose signatures are incompatible with [`ThreadProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms686736(v=vs.85)).

Comment: @RemyLebeau What do you mean about injecting more code? Are there simple examples? :-)

And I nerver thought use IPC to do it, I thought it maybe difficult for me.

Comment: This looks similar to what you are trying to do: https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/using-createremotethread-for-dll-injection-on-windows/

Comment: @JeunePrimeOrigines that article only explains how to get the DLL loaded, which the OP is already doing. It doesn't cover how to make additional calls into that DLL after it is loaded.

Comment: @JYP2011 - so if you're able to successfully load the DLL using CreateRemoteThread() as described in the link on my previous comment, perhaps an easy way is to try to rewrite your add() function so it will take single parameter using a structure. (e.g. struct { int a; int b; };). Essentially to make it compatible with ThreadProc signature as noted by RemyLebeau. additional reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575695/pass-more-than-one-argument-to-createthread

Comment: @JeunePrimeOrigines thanks for you quick reply.
typedef struct data{
  int a, b;
}*pdata;

I have try it in CreateThread, that is okay.


But I found that the first step about  calling GetModuleHandle("mydll") has failed -_-||
Its return code shows cannot found it. If I replace mydll with user32, that's okay.





so, the first part in the above I past has any error?

Comment: @JYP2011 - Is this applicable? - "The GetModuleHandle function succeeds only if the DLL module is already mapped into the address space of the process by load-time linking or by a previous call to LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx.", you may try to check if you need to call LoadLibrary before it. reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/run-time-dynamic-linking

Comment: yeah, ur rignt. After LoadLibrary, it success GetModuleHandle.
But failed in writing the parameter data in the third party process space.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8dZ9hpkw4g/   @JeunePrimeOrigines

Comment: updated:
use the following code to write local data to data in the third party process is ok.
 SIZE_T ReturnLength;
 BOOL bOk = WriteProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, pdata, pdata_local, sizeof(Data), &ReturnLength);@JeunePrimeOrigines

Comment: @JYP2011 - you check on WriteProcessMemory() API used by the example on my initial comment.

Comment: @JeunePrimeOrigines okay. the WriteProcessMemroy API sucess, but error occured when I call CreateRemoteThread, It will make the third party application crash....

Comment: @JYP2011 - Maybe the crash has something to do with the calling convention. The ThreadProc required by CreateRemoteThread uses "WINAPI" or __stdcall. The WINAPI  differs from __cdecl   (default on c/c++) on how it cleans up the stack. Perhaps you can check on this.

Comment: @JeunePrimeOrigines I add WINAPI and __stdcall like "extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  int __stdcall add(int a, int b)" or  "extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  int WINAPI add(int a, int b)" , and try it , the result make me sad.






Besides, how can I get the result return from the function add, assume that the CreateRemoteThread returns as expected.

Comment: @JYP2011 - I think I overlooked the result part when I suggested the struct. But i think you can still solve it by adding it as 3rd field of the structure parameter. (e.g. typedef struct data{ int a, b, result; }*pdata ), probably initialized as zero during WriteProcessMemory() and retrieve the result using ReadProcessMemory(). Just a theory and probably what I would also do if I'd try solve it.

Comment: if I use typedef struct data{int a, b, *result}*pdata.
the pdata point is the address of remote process. How can I read its field? @JeunePrimeOrigines

Comment: I'm not sure if you really need  "int *result". I think "int result;" is enough.  
=======================
struct data param;

param.a = 10;
param.b = 5;
param.result = 0; // optional

// allocate procesmem using VirtualAllocEx()
// copy param to procesmem using WriteProcessMemory()

add(procesmem); // call using CreateRemoteThread()

// wait until remote thread is done

// copy procesmem back to param using ReadProcessMemory()

printf("%d",param.result);

Comment: Then the add function may look like this:
// The add function reads field a and b, and write to result field.
dword add(LPVOID lpParam) {  struct data* data_ptr = (struct data*)lpParam; data_ptr->result = (data_ptr->a +  data_ptr->b); return 0; }

Answer (score 1):

I think the tricky part is to pass arguments when injecting the DLL.

There are at least two ways you can try:

1. Use your DLL path and name as parameters. The DLL's filename could be retrieved by [GetModuleHandleEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexa) and [GetModuleFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea)
2. Pass the parameters through the thread description. First, call [CreateRemoteThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread) with the flag CREATE_SUSPENDED, then resume it after you have a chance to set its description by [SetThreadDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreaddescription). Use [GetThreadDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreaddescription) in your DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH case to get the description.

Please refer to the [migi project](https://github.com/nomadsinteractive/migi) on Github to get the working sources.